# Print filenames while find and process to the pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a set of json files and I want to perform some operation on them (extract a tag). Command looks like this:

```
find ./fixtures/*.json | xargs cat | jq .[0].terms.customer[0].slug
```

`.[0].terms.customer[0].slug` is my query and not important here. Command above works OK. The output is something like:

```
"default"
"default"
"default"
"default"
"foo"
"foo"
"bar"
```

But how can I change shell command above to display a filename of processed file? I'd like to see the output like this:

```
1.json: "default"
2.json: "default"
3.json: "default"
4.json: "default"
5.json: "foo"
6.json: "foo"
7.json: "bar"
```

Tried with echo, but seems like output is redirected to pipe. Should I echo to stderr or better approach can be used here?

When I use `tee` command with `find ./fixtures/*.json | tee /dev/tty | xargs cat | jq .[0].terms.customer[0].slug` it shows me this:

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
4.json
5.json
6.json
"default"
"default"
"default"
"default"
"foo"
"foo"
"bar"
```

It's not something easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A while loop for printing the filename and processing its contents would be better.

```
find ./fixtures/*.json | while read f ; do echo -n "$f: " ; cat "$f" | jq .[0].terms.customer[0].slug ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `sed` in the `xargs` command like this:

```
find fixtures -name '*.json' -print0 | 
xargs -0 -I % bash -c 'sed "s~^~$1: ~" < <(jq ".[0].terms.customer[0].slug" "$1")' - %
```

**How it works:**

- `print0` and `xargs -0` is recommended to deal with file names with white-spaces or special characters.
- `sed` command is run on output of `jq` and replaced each line start by filename and colon.
- Hyphen before `%` is just a place holder for `bash -c` command line that populates `$0` as hyphen.

Comment: Great answer.  Please add explanation about why `-` is needed before `%`.